# Control replacements in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like

`test [test id="123" /] test [test id="234" /] [test id="345" /] test`

How can I replace each `[test ... /]` with something else, but control each replacement (by index) ?

I may want first match to be replaced with something, but the 2nd one with something else

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
$index = 0;

preg_replace_callback('/\[test\sid="(?P<id>.+?)"\s*\/\]/', function() use (&$index) {
    var_dump($index, func_get_args());
    $index++;

}, $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0alWHf).

You can access `$index` to determine what iteration of the replacement you are on.